# compress videos in flutter

Tags: flutter, video, dart

I face one issue in my application, I want to pick video from the gallery, then compress the video to limit size.

**For Example:**
Size of video picked from the gallery: 20MB ----> I want to compress this video to be 2MB maximum.

**I used** this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_video_compress, but still I cannot reduce the size to what I want, It means I cannot give a limit of video compression.

Comment: please post a piece of code you have tried

Comment: ```final compressedVideoInfo = await _flutterVideoCompress.compressVideo(
      videoFile.path,
      quality: VideoQuality.DefaultQuality,
      deleteOrigin: false,
    );```

I can not defune max Size, just quality  :(

Comment: check my answer!

Answer (score 1):

You should try `quality: VideoQuality.LowQuality` for best compression,

```
 final MediaInfo info = await _flutterVideoCompress.compressVideo(
          file.path,
          deleteOrigin: true,
          quality: VideoQuality.LowQuality,
        );
```

Comment: Thank you, I already used LowQuality but still size of video too larg, I want to compress to limit, for example I want to say compress until size of video be 2MB

Comment: @Ravinder Kumar Is there any way to set the output file path?